# Why Google crawler is not blocked with CAPTCHA?

Tags: web-crawler

I run my crawler on some particular website `www.example.com`. The crawler is blocked by CAPTCHA after ~100 entries. On the other hand, when I enter Google and search for `site:www.example.com` I get 100,000 results found, and the results are cached correctly by Google.

My question: how come the Google bot is not blocked and I am? Is it because of thousands of distinct IPs Google uses or there is some other trick?

Comment: It's most likely because the web site owner explicitly allows Google to do so (probably by IP)

Answer (score 0):

In general, site owners are interested in getting traffic from search engines, so they might even whiteliste Google.

By the way, are you using timeout between your queries? If you query too often, you may be blocked because you create too much load for the server.